# cannot find real location of %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json in explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I can edit settings.json in vscode but I want to actually locate the physical file. According to vscode doc https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings  the user settings file is located here:

```
Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
```

but when going to it with explorer I cannot see any settings.json

Comment: On Windows, it would be like this: `C:\Users\Godzilla\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### Settings file locations
>
> Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:
>
> Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`

- from [Settings documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

But how do figure out where `%APPDATA%` is on your system?  One easy way is to create a keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) like this:

```
{
  "key":  "alt+q",       // whatever you want
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "echo ${env:APPDATA}"
  }
},
```

When this is run the variable `${env:APPDATA}` will be resolved and printed out.

It will be something like this:

`C:\Users\Cerberus\AppData\Roaming`

so for the full path add `\Code\User\settings.json` to the end of that.  Or use this in the keybinding:

`"text": "echo ${env:APPDATA}\\Code\\User\\settings.json"`

outputs: `C:\Users\Rodan\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`